# Render icon for bottom navigator error, but got: number

Tags: javascript, react-native, bottomtabs

Why does this error appear? whereas in the previous version of react native it worked 0.66.4, API 29 with openjdk8. I don't know, I've tried using the previous version but a rendering error appears.

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: number.
> Check the render method of `Icon`.

**TabItem.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import { IconAbout, IconAboutActive, IconHome, IconHomeActive, IconNearby, IconNearbyActive} from '../../assets'
import { WARNA_UTAMA, WARNA_DISABLE } from '../../utils/constant'

const TabItem = ({ isFocused, onPress, onLongPress, label }) => {
    const Icon = () => {
        if (label === 'Home') return isFocused ? <IconHomeActive /> : <IconHome />
        if (label === 'Nearby') return isFocused ? <IconNearbyActive /> : <IconNearby />
        if (label === 'About') return isFocused ? <IconAboutActive /> : <IconAbout />
      
        return <IconHome />
      }
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={onPress}
            onLongPress={onLongPress}
            style={styles.container}>
            <Icon />
            <Text style={styles.text(isFocused)}>
              {label}
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}

export default TabItem

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    text: (isFocused) =>  ({
        fontSize: 13,
        color: isFocused ? WARNA_UTAMA : WARNA_DISABLE, 
    })
})
```

**BottomNavigator.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import TabItem from '../TabItem';

const BottomNavigator = ({ state, descriptors, navigation }) => {
    const focusedOptions = descriptors[state.routes[state.index].key].options;

  if (focusedOptions.tabBarVisible === false) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <View style={ styles.container }>
      {state.routes.map((route, index) => {
        const { options } = descriptors[route.key];
        const label =
          options.tabBarLabel !== undefined
            ? options.tabBarLabel
            : options.title !== undefined
            ? options.title
            : route.name;

        const isFocused = state.index === index;

        const onPress = () => {
          const event = navigation.emit({
            type: 'tabPress',
            target: route.key,
            canPreventDefault: true,
          });

          if (!isFocused && !event.defaultPrevented) {
            navigation.navigate(route.name);
          }
        };

        const onLongPress = () => {
          navigation.emit({
            type: 'tabLongPress',
            target: route.key,
          });
        };

        return (
          <TabItem 
              key={index}
              label={label}
              isFocused={isFocused}
              onPress={onPress}
              onLongPress={onLongPress}
          />
        );
      })}
    </View>
  );
}

export default BottomNavigator

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        flexDirection: 'row',
        backgroundColor: '#FFFF',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        paddingHorizontal: 48,
        paddingVertical: 8,
        borderRadius: 50,
    }
})
```

**Route.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import {About, Home, Nearby, Splash} from '../pages';
import {BottomNavigator} from '../components';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const MainApp = () => {
  return (
      {
        <Tab.Navigator tabBar={props => <BottomNavigator {...props} />}>
          <Tab.Screen
            name="Home"
            component={Home}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
          />
          <Tab.Screen
            name="Nearby"
            component={Nearby}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
          />
          <Tab.Screen
            name="About"
            component={About}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
          />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      }
  );
};

const Router = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Splash">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Splash"
        component={Splash}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="MainApp"
        component={MainApp}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default Router;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

This code, should can be rendered custom local icon correctly

Comment: Update : instead of me being bothered by icon rendering bugs, I'm using the react-native-vector-icons library . If anyone wants to correct their question, good luck and stay safe